How to seal an interior crawlspace hatch that pipes run through?
There is a 2'x2' hatch covering the opening between our unfinished basement and the crawlspace beneath a laundry room addition. I'm hoping to improve the seal between the crawlspace and unfinished basement to reduce humidity and insect intrusion, as the crawlspace is much more open to the elements than the basement. Unfortunately a duct, water, and wastewater pipes run through the hatch.
Here is a photo of the rough approximate of a hatch that the previous owner designed:

Any suggestions on how to fill in the rest of those spaces while still being able to remove the hatch when needed?

It sounds like the opening is 2'×2' including the pipes.  So consider who and what needs to get down there routinely.
I would go for a smaller hatch that opens easily, combined with a new tidy piece of ply around the pipes that's sealed t the pipes with silicone.  That could be opened up if necessary, cutting off the silicone, so long as the smaller hatch was big enough for routine access.
For comparison I have a hatch up into storage that (converted from remembered metric) is about 16-18" square; I have to put my shoulders through it on the diagonal.  In a church where I did many odd jobs many years ago, the hatch down into a crawl space was smaller still, probably only 12" on the short side - one reason I went in there so much as a skinny teenager was that some people couldn't fit. Once in there there were similar sized roughly horizontal gaps.
In your case, I'd have 3 pieces of ply:

the new hatch, full width (in the orientation of your photo) but partial depth, hinged to...
a piece going along the front of the pipes, shaped to fit closely then sealed.  This should be screwed down
a piece along the back of the pipes, again sealed to them (and the previous piece) and screwed down.

I'd also think hard about insulation and draught-sealing all sections
